# Issue with __Event validation field

Tags: asp.net

Hi Can someone tell me if I get the below error

```
Invalid postback or callback argument. 
Event validation is enabled using in configuration or 
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` in a page. 

For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback
or callback events originate from the server control that originally 
rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the 
ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register 
the postback or callback data for validation."
```

How can I find out which control and which page is throwing the error given that I am working with a large website having multiple pages and each page having n number of controls .